I Have Oracle Version 11 and i want use EntityFramework Core 8
my Company Use Oracle Version 11 and my application use Entity Framework for connection to it.
in Oracle.EntityFramework v8 no support for oracle version 11 anymore but i want use json support in entity framework 8. if i Update NuGet package of entity Framework i can't connect and query My Oracle v11 ....
how i resolve this issue?
current Situation:
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.16" />
<PackageReference Include="Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.21.9" />

Need Situation:
Entity Framework 8
Oracle.EntityFramework 7 Or 8

You simple cannot. There is no binary compatibility between EF Core 8 and EF Core 7. Interfaces changed, provider interface changed.

Upgrade from Oracle 11g to a version that is not 20+ years old and is supported. Oracle 11g does not have JSON functions/support as those were implemented from Oracle 12.
